# How to Stop IIS with PowerShell?

Tags: iis, powershell

I am learning PowerShell and trying to stop IIS on a remote server.

I am  using PowerGUI Script Editor that I started in admin mode.

I have this code

```
$service = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName 'myserver'  -Filter "Name='IISAdmin'"
$service
$service.StopService();
$service.State
```

State always comes back as running. I don't know why it does not stop.

Edit

Error I get when running

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'myserver' { Stop-Service IISAdmin }
```

> Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message :
>   The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request.
>   Verify that the service on the destination is running and is
>   accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the
>   WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or
>   WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following
>   command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service:
>   "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Edit2

I found this and it seems to work. I don't know how to get the information back from Stop-Service so I had to use the other way to get it to me. If you know how please let me know.

```
Stop-Service -Force -InputObject $(Get-Service -Computer myserver -Name IISAdmin)
$service = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName 'myserver '  -Filter "Name='IISAdmin'"
$service.State
```

This works. I don't understand why. The only thing I can think off is I had to use -Force as it would not stop the server otherwise so maybe that is a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using PsExec \Server2 -u Administrator -p somePassword IISReset /STOP

or using PowerGUI Script Editor

```
$service = Get-WmiObject -computer 'ServerA' Win32_Service -Filter "Name='IISAdmin'"
$service
$service.InvokeMethod('StopService',$Null)
$service.State
```

Try using

```
$server = "servername"
$siteName = "Default Web Site"
$iis = [ADSI]"IIS://$server/W3SVC"
$site = $iis.psbase.children | where { $_.keyType -eq "IIsWebServer" -AND
$_.ServerComment -eq $siteName }
$site.serverstate=3
$site.setinfo()
```

Comment: I tried your second way all ready(I can try it again if I missed something). While doing that I saw the short hand method for StopService....Just tried your code and same result.

Comment: Can you try setting the serverstate ($site.serverState = 3) to 3 (which is stopped)

Comment: when do I set it to 3. I was just looking when I do $service I see a return value of 3. Is that the State value?

Comment: Oops serverstate 3 is STOPPING. USE State 4 to STOP it.

Comment: why does a siteName need to be specified?

Comment: To stop just that site. if you want to stop ALL sites do not set it and use $site = $iis.psbase.children | where { $_.keyType -eq "IIsWebServer"}

Comment: I get alot of errors doing this. first one I get is "The following exception was thrown when trying to enumerate the collection: "Unknown error (0x80005000)"....$site = <<<<  $iis.psbase.children | where { $_.keyType -eq "IIsWebServer"}

Answer (score 9):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName myserver { Stop-Service W3SVC}
```

Comment: I get an error please see edit. Also what is the difference doing it this way vs the other way?

Comment: Read about PowerShell remoting here:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

Comment: Do I have to do those steps on both machines?

Comment: `Cannot find any service with service name 'IISAdmin'.`

Comment: IISAdmin should be W3SVC instead

Answer (score 9):

to stop IIS (like "rightclick > stop" on the server in the iis-Manager):

```
spsv iisadmin,was,w3svc -pa
```

means:

```
stop-service -name iisadmin,was,w3svc -passThru # -passThru is optional but basically outputs the result
```

(alternative: `gsv iisadmin,was,w3svc |spsv -pa|sasv -pa` to restart the service and output the result BUT in this example JUST the second -pa is optional!!! FYI: gsv=get-service, sasv=start-service, spsv=stop-service, pa=passThru)

Answer (score 8):

You can stop/restart iis remotely with iisreset:

```
iisreset [computername]
```

Comment: I will try this but still unsure why the other ways don't work. Also how do I get the state and stuff back using this way?

Answer (score 5):

There is another, simple way how to stop IIS = just run from Powershell

```
iisreset /stop
```

and to start IIS, just

```
iisreset /start
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of dealing with WMI objects. Instead I'd propose using `iisreset /stop` in conjunction with PowerShell remoting. So, essentially this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'myserver' -ScriptBlock { & iisreset /stop }
```

You can swap out `/stop` with `/start` to start IIS on the remote servers as well.

If you don't want to leverage the `iisreset.exe` and instead use pure PowerShell, you can start / stop the `W3SVC` service instead:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'myserver' -ScriptBlock { Stop-Service W3SVC }
```

And replace `Stop-Service` with `Start-Service` to start it again. The `W3SVC` service is IIS.